# Catch uncaught exceptions inside an Android Service

Tags: android, service

I'm having some difficulty tracking down an error in my Android code. I spawn an unbound service from my main activity with:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}
```

I want it to be constantly running as long as the device is on. For some reason it just crashes silently and I'm having a lot of difficulty finding out why.

I've tried getting the thread that the service is running in and adding an uncaught exception handler to it but no luck:

```
private void onStart() {
        mIsRunning = true;
        if(mUncaughtExceptionHandler == null) {
            mUncaughtExceptionHandler = new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
                @Override
                public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable throwable) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error in ClientService");
                    throwable.printStackTrace();
                }
            };
            Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(mUncaughtExceptionHandler);
        }
    }
```

Does anyone have any advice on how to debug this?

Comment: You got a crash or just the Service got killed?

Comment: The service no longer runs.

Comment: You can try to return START_STICKY rather than START_REDELIVER_INTENT

Comment: I originally had START_STICKY. I don't see why that would make a difference either way though.

Comment: What I meant by failing silently is that there's nothing in the logcat.

Comment: from the docs: START_STICKY If the service's process is killed while it is started (after returning from onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)), then leave it in the started state but don't retain this delivered intent. Later the system will try to re-create the service.

Comment: Again, why would this matter? START_REDELIVER_INTENT does the exact same thing as START_STICKY aside from redelivering the intent that was used to start the Service. Which I want to happen.